# appending to a list in while loop without overwriting the list

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop, append

I have written some code that changes the state of an element in a list, if a random number is greater than the elements associated score (in another list).

I am trying to create a list of lists of the states as the while loop proceeds, however this results in a list of lists where all the lists are the final state of the code. I am using the append function in each of the conditionals in the while loop.

Sorry if i havent explained this well, I am quite new to coding. Here is the code, it probably explains it better than I can.

```
import random 
random.seed(100)
f = random.randint(0,3)
m = random.randint(0,3)
s = random.randint(0,3)

seq = [0.2]*s + [0.5]*m + [0.8]*f
random.shuffle(seq)
state = [0]*len(seq)


record = []
count = 0

while count < len(seq):
    if count == 0 and random.random() < seq[count]:
        state[count]+=1
        print(state)
        record.append(state)
        count += 1
    elif count == 0 and random.random() > seq[count]:
        state[count]+=0
        print(state)
        record.append(state)
        count += 0
    elif count > 0  and random.random() < seq[count]:
        state[count]+=1
        state[count-1]-=1
        print(state)
        record.append(state)
        count += 1
    elif count > 0  and random.random() > seq[count]:
        state[count]+=0
        state[count-1]-=0
        print(state)
        record.append(state)
        count += 0

print(record)
```

The `print(state)` function shows what I want to have a list from in the kernel. However the 'record' list only has a list of the final state of the program.

Here are the expected list and the list i get

```
expectedlist = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]

listiget = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

I believe I am not using the append function correctly. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need

> record.append(state.copy())

try changing your code to

```py
import random 
random.seed(100)
f = random.randint(0,3)
m = random.randint(0,3)
s = random.randint(0,3)

seq = [0.2]*s + [0.5]*m + [0.8]*f
print(seq)
random.shuffle(seq)
state = [0]*len(seq)

record = []
count = 0

while count < len(seq):
    if count == 0 and random.random() < seq[count]:
        state[count]+=1
        record.append(state.copy())
        count += 1
    elif count == 0 and random.random() > seq[count]:
        state[count]+=0
        record.append(state.copy())
        count += 0
    elif count > 0  and random.random() < seq[count]:
        state[count]+=1
        state[count-1]-=1
        record.append(state.copy())
        count += 1
    elif count > 0  and random.random() > seq[count]:
        state[count]+=0
        state[count-1]-=0
        record.append(state.copy())
        count += 0

print(record)
```

My output

> [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]

Hopefully this example makes it clear

```py
a = []
b = [4,5,6]

a.append(b)
b[1] = 2
print(a)
```

this will output

> [[4, 2, 6]]

and not

> [[4, 5, 6]]

because the append is maintaining a reference to the list `b`

Comment: Yes this makes it very clear. I thought there was a simpler answer to this than what i was tryng to do. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question I find your code logic is totally right however you are missing these things as I think:

1. append method is used Add an item to the end of the list so instead use add method. in documentation --https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html
2. as per the previous answers state will remain referring to the current state without copying it
   so the code will be as following :
   use this

   ```
      record.add(state.copy())
   ```

instead of
record.append(state)

Answer (score 0):

`state` only ever refers to the same list, so when you append it to `record`, you're just appending references to the same list. Meaning that previously appended `state`s will all be identical to the current state of `state`. You should be copying `state` before appending it to `record`, like `state[:]`, `state.copy()` or via [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).

Comment: ah i see. I have implemented this and it seems to have worked thank you.